# Cannot change database directory of MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, path, ubuntu-14.04, database

I want to change the directory of MongoDb. I tried using mongod --dbpath and also changing the path of directory in mongod.conf. Follwing are commands I used -

> mongod --dbpath /home/mongodata

and

> dbpath = /home/mongodata 
>   in /etc/mongod.conf
>
> chown $USER -R /home/mongodata

But when I import data into database, it still goes to /var/lib/mongodb folder.
Please can anyone suggest how I can change the default directory of mongodb database?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and MongoDb vz 3.0.6.

Comment: Please place questions about administration and maintenance of MongoDB on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you stop and restart the service.  You probably already have this answered by now, but for others, I put the following.  You can modify the below code for your specific needs.  Hope it helps.

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo mv mongodb /home/mongodata
sudo ln -s /home/mongodata /your-former-path
sudo chown mongodb:mongoldb /home/mongodata
sudo service mongod start
```